# Town Of Pixels - Getting Traffic

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need some inputs and feedback on one of my application which i released a week back. Its name is Town of Pixels (http://www.townofpixels.com). Its majorly for designers, photographers and artists who want to showcase their work in a personalized way.

Now i have a concern. I have done nothing to get much traffic. So my google anaytics shows poor results. How can i improve this. I have taken care of SEO upto my knowledge. Please help me with some tips of how to move forward and also some feedback about the application.

Thanks,
Abhishek

Comment: Advertise, SEO is not enough alone.

Comment: Hire someone who specializes in SEO. Also, advertise. Take advantage of social networks: Facebook, Twitter, Google+, MySpace, etc. -- Keep in mind that the stack sites are not social networks or places to advertise free of charge. :)